# How Do I Implement Google Maps Marker Details? *Pictures*

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working on an Android app for my senior project, and my app has a Google Map that shows the location of campus events via a Marker.

My question is, how do I implement [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypWzZ.jpg) when a marker is pressed on? This is what the Maps app by Google does when you click on a marker on the map. Is this something that's within the Google Maps API, or is it something I would have to implement on my own as an activity?

Comment: There are examples how you can implement click on marker and for second you can get all of those informations by making request to Google Maps and parsing `JSON` or maybe to implement `webivew` and show that in `webivew` but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: You need [this - Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details), more on [Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/).

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: HEATH3N Yeah, pretty much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no good built-in way to achieve what you'd like. While the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details) does exist and you may be able to use it, it is really meant for adding actual places rather than ephemeral events, and you will be required to add an address, place types, etc. Also keep in mind:

> Newly-added places enter a moderation queue to be considered for addition to the Google Places database. Places that are not accepted by the moderation process will continue to be retrievable through the place ID in the app that submitted them, but will no longer appear in the results of get-current-place requests, the api picker, or any other API method. Places that pass moderation will be visible to all apps and on Google Maps.

Furthermore, Place Add has been deprecated since June 2017 and will be removed in June 2018.

It shouldn't be too hard to roll your own solution and you'll benefit from not being restricted to the fields afforded by the API.